# Lambda expression in loops in python weird result

Tags: python, lambda

I haven't used much functional programming core features like `lambda` or `map`, but I have recently found it useful. I am using the following lambda function and it is not generating the desired results.

```
def multiplier():
    return [lambda x:x**i for i in range(10)]

print [m(2) for m in multiplier()] #output is [512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512]
```

Why do I get this behaviour? Here in lambda, `i` closes on the last value of list i.e 9 and hence when I pass parameter m(2) ..2**9 =512 is printed.

EDIT:
My exact question is as per my understanding , final output should be x**i; i ranging from 0 to 9 and where x=2 in my example. So why only i=9 is considered for all the 10 loops?

Can anyone explain as why is this happening?

Comment: My exact question  is as per my understanding , final output should be x**i; i ranging from 0 to 9 and where x=2 in my example. So why only i=9 is considered for all the 10 loops? @poke

Comment: See the linked question, it’s the same thing: `i` is lexically scoped, so when the lambda is executed only then it evaluates `i`, at which point the loop has completely run.